# REST cookie authentication, Post 403

Tags: 8, cookies

I am logged in to my Drupal account and if I use the jQuery code from [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/3-post-for-creating-content-entities) then I can make a post request to my site and create a node.
But if I try from another site, like my local host or a third party site, I get 403 error.

I tried with a Get request from [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/2-get-for-reading-content-entities), using jQuery, I could perform get the request, on both the Drupal site and an external site.

But I am unable to post, patch or delete from an external site using jquery and cookie authentication.

I'm not sure but I have a feeling it has something to do with the cookie not being sent with the request?

I can use basic_authentication but that requires the login credentials to be sent, which I do not want.

how can I get the cookie authentication to work with jQuery?

Comment: What does "I am unable" mean, in terms of the HTTP request and response?

Comment: Hi @cilefen I send the request using the jQuery demo https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/3-post-for-creating-content-entities, but the response I get is 403 error.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I get the cookie authentication to work with jQuery?

This is not possible.  See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36318930); the browser only allows you to use JS to access the cookies for the current domain; you cannot use JS to access cookies from other domains.

This is a basic security feature of modern browsers.

Alternatives:

- Implement [Simple OAuth](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_oauth) on the server
- Implement [JWT](https://www.drupal.org/project/jwt) on the server
- Implement something like [Capacitor HTTP plugin](https://github.com/capacitor-community/http) for giving the browser access to your domain's cookies in all of your clients